# How to create new empty column in Spark by Scala with just column name and data type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Like adding new column in RDBMS, it is not necessary to fill in the column with data but should provide column name and data type. I'd like to do the same in Spark dataframe but not necessarily specified in Schema, I hope the new column can create in ad hoc way

```
 val dfWithNewColumn = df.withColumn("new_col", IntgerType)
```

the point is precisely provide the type instead of Spark inference. But I couldn't see any solution other than change in Schema or make default value to the new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like that?

```
val dfWithNewColumn =  df.withColumn("new_col", lit(null).cast("int"))
```

It will create column of nulls without spark type infer.